# How to create e-mail reminders in Django

Tags: python, django, email, cron

I am looking to send e-mail reminders to users X amount of time before a scheduled even.  I've been reading through the documentation for [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/), which seems to support such scheduled mailing, but am unable to find such functionality in the code.

My thought is to have a script in my project that gets called by cron every several minutes that will will loop through event occurrence objects, check the "lead time" against the current time, and send an e-mail through the default Django e-mail backend if needed.  However, I'd like to avoid re-inventing the wheel here if there is an elegant existing solution for scheduling e-mail.

Comment: There's a trick to avoid reinventing the wheel.  It's called search.  Search Stack Overflow.  Search Django Community.  Search Google.  Post your results and any **specific** questions on the applications you find.

Answer (score 1):

Roll your own.

Sending an email is trivial enough already. The coding required to complete the task will be application specific. What more can a pre-built package offer you? What features did you have in mind? All I can think of is a queryset which returns objects based on an arbitrary timestamp but it would add more complexity than it saves so I don't see much hope.